# Disable Firebase for specific-productflavors

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud messaging to get the notifications and download the google-json file from its console and have put under the specific product flavour "**Building(alias)**". Now i have one more product flavour i have "**Apartment(alias)**" and i want to disable the firebase for it.

Problem: if I put google-services.json under the "Building" product flavour then for "Apartment" flavour it's not compiling and giving an error "File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it".

I don't want to enable the firebase for one of the above product flavour, so could you please help me what should i do and how we can resolve.